# how to draw lines manually in a list view in android

Tags: android, listview

in my app i an showing a list view. The list view is a history record. It may be of one data at a time or 2 or more data too.

My problem is i am showing a black background, in such case the lines between each data are not visible clearly at all. The line is completely absent after the last data.

Some times if there is only one data, there is no line next to that data. How to solve these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's place an View tag below the last TextView in your content page, and set following properties for it

```
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: This is pretty standard as far as I know too... might as well accept it dude. This goes on the layout for the list item btw.